# How to include the reference of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll on Mono2.10?

Tags: c#, mono, openxml-sdk, moma

I am using C#.net Windows Desktop Application.I want to run these application with other platform also. So, i am using Mono 2.10 as a cross compiler.While running,unexpectedly my Application is terminated by saying the error message like

**Error:Could not open the selected folder.**
**Could not load a file or assembly 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll,version=2.0.5022.0, culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.**

I don't know what is problem here...I have installed openxml sdk2.0 on c:\program files\open xml sdk\v2\lib\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll.

and also put my application eXe on on the same place for testing purpose...

Please guide me to solve this issue...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should also ensure you set a reference to `WindowsBase`. This is required to use the SDK as it handles `System.IO.Packaging` (which is used for unzipping and opening the compressed .docx/.xlsx/.pptx as an OPC document).

Comment: i have set a reference of the WindowsBase in C#.Net(4.0) through project explorer window.But till i am not able to solve that issue...what i do next?

Comment: if you have more projects than one within solution try to include to others too. may be you are including to wrong one

Comment: Thanks. I didn't have `System.IO.Packaging` specified

Comment: This is weird that user is getting run time error. The moment you start trying to use classes like `SpreadsheetDocument` in cod the compiler itself starts giving error. On run-time it should pick `WindowsBase.dll` from Global Assembly Cache (GAC) of .Net Framework.

Answer (score 22):

Being new to this myself, here's what I did:

I'm using MS Visual Studio 2010 Pro.

1. Download and install the OpenXML SDK
2. Within my project in Visual Studio, select "Project" then "Add Reference"
3. Select the "Browse" tab
4. In the "Look in:" pull down, navigate to:
   C:\Program Files(x86)\Open XML SDK\V2.0\lib  and select the "DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll
5. Hit OK
6. In the "Solution Explorer" (on the right for me), the "References" folder now shows the DocumentFormat.OpenXML library.
7. Right-click on it and select Properties
8. In the Properties panel, change "Copy Local" to "True".

You should be off and running now using the DocumentFormat classes.

Answer (score 7):

select DocumentFormat.OpenXml under references , view it's properties, and set the Copy Local option to True so that it copies it to the output folder. That worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

Goto Nuget Package manager and search for openxml. And install DocumentFormat.OpenXml

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me:

1. Add a folder to the project call it `ThirdParty`.
2. Add in the `ThirdParty` folder both `DocumentFormat.OpenXML.dll` and  `WindowsBase.dll`
3. Make sure the the project uses the `ThirdParty` dir as reference for both the DLLs
4. Build and published to an external server.

Answer (score 1):

Well, In my applications I just need to Add a reference to "DocumentFormat.OpenXml" under .Net tab and both references (DocumentFormat.OpenXml and WindowsBase) are always added automatically. But They are not included within the Bin folder. So when the Application is published to an external server I always place DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll under the Bin folder manually. Or set the reference "Copy Local" property to true.

Comment: I have used this solution successfully in VisualStudio 2017 with Website projects.  At present, I copy the .net reference assembly from <system drive>\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\<.net version desired>\<dllname>.dll to my website's /bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have DocumentFormat.OpenXML.dll in the same folder as your application - or in the 'bin' path if you are developing an ASP.NET application.  However, I'm not certain that the OpenXML SDK is supported on non-Windows operating systems - you may need to look into a third-party solution.

Yes, this answer is right, the only difference is that you copy your .dll into bin folder of the project.

Answer (score 0):

After viewing and changed the properties to DocumentFormat.OpenXml, I also had to change the Specific Version to false.

Answer (score 0):

I found that when mixed with PCL libraries the above problem presented itself, and whilst it is true that the WindowsBase library contains System.IO.Packaging I was using the OpenXMLSDK-MOT 2.6.0.0 library which itself provides it's own copy of the physical System.IO.Packaging library. The reference that was missing for me could be found as follows in the csharp project

```
<Reference Include="System.IO.Packaging, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\packages\OpenXMLSDK-MOT.2.6.0.0\lib\System.IO.Packaging.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

I downgraded my version of the XMLSDK to 2.6 which then seemed to fix this problem up for me. But you can see there is a physical assembly System.IO.Packaging.dll

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was that `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll` existed in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) on my Win7 development box. So when publishing my project in VS2013, it found the file in the GAC and therefore omitted it from being copied to the publish folder.

Solution: remove the DLL from the GAC.

1. Open the GAC root in Windows Explorer (Win7: `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly`)
2. Search for `OpenXml`
3. Delete any appropriate folders (or to be safe, cut them out to your desktop in case you should want to restore them)

There may be a more proper way to remove a GAC file (below), but that is what I did and it worked.
`gacutil –u DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll`

Hope that helps!