# Azure, ClosedXML: Build will NOT include DocumentFormat.OpenXML in the bin folder of my application

Tags: c#, azure, openxml, closedxml

I set the dll to copy local on build as seen here:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbu8X.png]

It shows up in my drop folder on Azure:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9TXJ.png]

but it never makes it into the bin folder of my actual application as seen here:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Qxdd.png]

as a result:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAXu4.png]

Anyone have experience with this specific dll not getting where you need it to be?

Thanks!

Comment: It appears as though this bug has been seen by others: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258363/how-to-include-the-reference-of-documentformat-openxml-dll-on-mono2-10)

Comment: I have had no issues with that. Did you manually add the reference to DocumentFormant.OpenXml, or it was the automatic reference added by the ClosedXML? Try removing the reference and adding it manually. In the matter of truth, what I do is, create a solution folder where I put all third party assemblies that are not from NuGet and that are not from core .NET Framework, and I add reference from my folder. Interesting, now I see that DocumentFormat.OpenXML is also on NuGet - just remove the reference and add it from NuGet.

Comment: and yes, the WindowsBase is also absolutely required reference, which is not explicitly obvious ...

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. ClosedXML actually added the DocumentFormat.OpenXml nuget package as a dependency, so that's the one I'm currently using.

Answer (score 0):

To fix a similar issue, I had to remove all references to DocumentFormat.OpenXML and ClosedXML. Then, I also uninstalled the OpenXML 2.5 SDK.  I was able to use the ClosedXML nuget package and everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

ClosedXML.dll depends on DocumentFormat.OpenXML.dll so you need to have them both to work with some methods in ClosedXML. If you use NuGet it should add references automatically to these packages.