# Updating an old C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

So I'm a fairly new developer, and was hoping someone might explain some things to me and help me understand how I can complete my task.

Okay so we have a "Web aplication" for one of our services that was written in C# quite some time ago. It has come to my employers attention, and he has requested me to update it to the newest framework/add or remove packages and make it build again (it doesn't build right now).

So the issue comes when I am adding packages. I have tried the old method of copying DLL files that are missing manually since the VPC does not allow for "NuGet" usage. I have tried to do this at home with NuGet and still failed.

Mostly I get errors of type:

> Could not load file or assembly 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml,
> Version=2.0.5022.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken="CustomNumber"' or
> one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
> does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
> 0x80131040).

**Note: CustomNumber represents the public key token I just didn't copy it.**

One is for DocumentFormat.OpenXml the other is for Ajax.min control toolkit.

Can anyone give me any pointers or explanations on how to update old projects, or how to even solve them?
Is there a specific way or method on how you solve problems like this or is it just basic googling untill you burn? (I have tried googling but I still got stuck)

Comment: `since the VPC does not allow for "NuGet" usage.` Much pain is coming your way if you can't access NuGet.

Comment: Have you seen to what framework was targeted the original project? maybe you're trying to use packages tht target newer frameworks? only throwing ideas

Comment: Please add information about which framework the old project targeted (I assume .NET Framework 4.x?), and which one you want to target now (I assume .NET 5.0). Reminder: ".NET Framework" is the old framework which isn't compatible with ".NET Core" or the newest simply called ".NET".

Comment: Looks like "ajax.min.js" can be found at: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ajax-min (https://tomflidr.github.io/ajax.js/builds/1.0.6/ajax.min.js)

Comment: Hi tarad, any update about this issue?

Comment: Hello, I have been satisfied with the awser from @user9938 however I have not yet finished the task, since its a "low priority" task and I work on it when I have spare time. Will post updates and follow up questions when I will be working on it.

Comment: Well. Thanks for your feedback and that is your choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add a reference to `WindowsBase`?

**VS 2019 / VS 2017**:

In VS menu,

- Click **Project**
- Select **Add Reference...**
- Click **Assemblies**
- Check **WindowsBase**
- Click **OK**

Also see: [How to include the reference of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll on Mono2.10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258363/how-to-include-the-reference-of-documentformat-openxml-dll-on-mono2-10)

If you're looking for the latest version, you'll want to look at:

[What's new in .NET 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dotnet-five)

[What is .NET Framework](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/dotnet/what-is-dotnet-framework)

[Download .NET, .NET Core, and .NET Framework](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download)

**Github**: [Open-XML-SDK](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK)

**NuGet**: [DocumentFormat.OpenXml](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/)

Since you stated that you're a "fairly new developer", below is some information that may be useful to you.

**ildasm**

If you're interested in viewing which assemblies are used in a .NET DLL file or .NET .exe file, you can use `ildasm.exe` from the Windows Kit.

- Download and install Windows 10 SDK (if not already installed): https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk/

**Note**: SDKs can be found in `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\` (ex: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows)

`ildasm.exe` can be found in one or more of the following locations (given that the SDK was installed in the default location):

**Win 10**:

- `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools
- `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\x64
- `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7.2 Tools
- `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7.2 Tools\x64
- `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.2 Tools
- `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.2 Tools\x64
  ...

**Win 8.1**:

- `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools
- `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\x64

**Win 7**:

- `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools
- `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x64
- `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\
- `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\x64

**Run** `ildasm.exe`

- Double-click `ildasm.exe` to run it (or open a `cmd` window and type `ildasm.exe`)
- Click **File**
- Select **Open**
- Choose your DLL file or .exe file (ex: TestDLL35.dll)
- Double-click **MANIFEST** to open it in a new window

You'll see something like the following:

[image]
**...**
[image]

When you see: `.assembly extern <name>` (ex: `.assembly extern System.Core`), this specifies an assembly that is required. Look at `.ver` inside the curly brackets to see the version of the assembly being used. For a .NET assembly this, is the .NET version for that library (ex: 3:5:0:0), shows that .NET 3.5 is used.

[image]

If one looks at ".ver" for `.assembly DocumentFormat.OpenXml`, the version shows as `2:0:5022:0` which is version 2.0.5022.0.

---

**NuGet packages**

Here's some information about NuGet packages, if you install one (at home). If one installs a NuGet package, it can be found in  `%UserProfile%\.nuget\packages`. For example, the latest NuGet package `DocumentFormat.OpenXml`, can be found in `C:\Users\<username>\.nuget\packages\open-xml-sdk\<version>\lib\<.NET version>` (ex: C:\Users\TestUser\.nuget\packages\open-xml-sdk\2.9.1\lib\net46). OpenXml version 2.0, can be found in NuGet package `DocumentFormat.OpenXmlSDK` (C:\Users\<username>\.nuget\packages\documentformat.openxmlsdk\2.0.0\lib\Net35)

In Visual Studio, the following setting determines whether or not the .NuGet package is copied to your local project folder:

In VS menu:

- Click **Tools**
- Select **Options**
- Expand **NuGet Package Manager**
- Click **General**
- Under Package Management, look at the value for **Default package management format**.

**Note**: When **Packages.config** is specified, and a .NuGet package is installed in your project, it will be downloaded to `%UserProfile%\.nuget\packages\<NuGet package name>` and then copied to your solution folder (or project folder) to a folder called "packages". If **PackageReference** is specified, the .NuGet package is installed in your project, and it will be downloaded to `%UserProfile%\.nuget\packages\<NuGet package name>` where your project will reference it which ensures that all of your projects use the same version of the NuGet package (it won't be copied to your solution folder/project folder). Also some settings are different in the .csproj file.

The file you listed above may be from the NuGet package `DocumentFormat.OpenXmlSDK` (v.2.0.0) which looks like it requires .NET 3.5. The newest/lastest NuGet package for OpenXml is `DocumentFormat.OpenXml` (v.2.12.1) and DLL's exist for .NET 3.5, .NET 4.0, and .NET 4.6.

See [Package references (PackageReference) in project files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files) and [Migrate from packages.config to PackageReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference)

Comment: That's a lot of information for what is more likely a missing/incompatible assembly.

Comment: Yes, but since the poster stated, "So I'm a fairly new developer.." this information will be helpful/useful.

Comment: Possibly, but too much information could also confuse them.

Comment: I re-formatted the information to make it easier to follow.

Comment: Thanks very much, very well detailed and I will look further into it, and try to finish when I'm at work (Will post updates and follow up questions if necesary)

Answer (score 0):

Due to error, it is mostly caused by your pc environment and your PC cannot find `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll version 2.0.5022.0`. So one solution is to add this dll into GAC so that your environment can find that.

Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62764744/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-runtime-compilerservices-unsafe/62770487#62770487).

Comment: Unfortunatley this anwser was not usefull as to what causes the problem (since I already knew that it didn't find the .dll) and that the link provided was not directly referenced to my case but a specific case on a different dll.